# Prove that if $\mu (A) = \nu(A)$ for all $A \in s$, then this also holds for all $A \in M(s)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $s$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two measures on $M(s)$. Prove that if $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ for all $A \in s$, then this also holds for all $A \in M(s)$, i.e., $\mu=M$.

I think that I can start the solution with the monotone class lemma and continuity measure. Do you have any suggestions about the solution?

Comment: This fails for infinite measures. Consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$ and check the algebra generated by finite unions of dyadic intervals generates this sigma algebra. Define one measure as the carnality of the interval and the other as infinity. When the measure is finite, this is an easy application of continuity of measure and the monotone class lemma, like you mentioned.

Comment: M(s) is an algebra. Every element in M(s) can be written as a finite disjoint union of elements in s

Answer (score 1):

If $s$ is just a collection of subsets of $X$, without any additional condition on $s$, then the result is FALSE, even if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite $\sigma$-additive measures.

The issue is that $\{A\in M(s) : \mu(A)=\nu(A) \}$ may not be closed under intersection.

Example:

Let $\Omega =\{1,2,3\}$ and let $s=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$. Then $M(s)=2^\Omega$. 
Now consider $\mu$ measure defined on $M(s)$ by $\mu(\{1\})=1$, $\mu(\{2\})=0$ and $\mu(\{3\})=1$. Consider also $\nu$ measure defined on $M(s)$ by $\nu(\{1\})=0$, $\nu(\{2\})=1$ and $\nu(\{3\})=0$.

It is clear that $\mu(\{1,2\})=1=\nu(\{1,2\})$ and $\mu(\{2,3\})=1=\nu(\{2,3\})$. So $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ for all $A \in s$, but clearly, we don't have $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ for all $A \in M(s)$.

**Remark**: To make the result true you need to add two conditions: 1. $s$ must closed under intersection and 2. the measures must be finite.

Comment: Yes, actually s is closed under intersection and the complement of any set is a finite disjoint union of elements in s.

Answer (score 0):

If $M(s)$ is supposed to be the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by $s$, then 
it should suffice to use the definition of a measure and the general description of an element of $M(s)$. 
If $M(s)$ is not said algebra, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, M(s) is an algebra. Every element in M(s) can be written as a finite disjoint union of elements in s.